# IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor, but class was expected

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, model, mobilenet

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K63D2.png) --> error picture

When ı try to process my model ı have an error " java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor, but class was expected"

I have a mobilenet tflite model which is I trained, and I created a function to convert bitmap to bytebuffe and ı try to process my model but ı had this error and ı can't solve it, can you help me to solve this ?

the error is on this line "val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)"

[a part of outputgenerator func code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZajoW.png) --> you can click and see the line which causes this error

```
        val byteBuffer = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap)
        byteBuffer!!.rewind()
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)

        val inputFeature0 =
            TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

        val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
```

[convertBitmapToByteBuffer function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JmLk.png)

```
       val byteBuffer =
           ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 4 * 1 * 224 * 224 * 3)
       byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
       val intValues = IntArray(224 * 224 )
       bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
       var pixel = 0

       for (i in 0 until 224) {
           for (j in 0 until 224) {
               val `val` = intValues[pixel++]
               byteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` shr 16 and 0xFF) - 1) / 255.0f)
               byteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` shr 8 and 0xFF) - 1) / 255.0f)
               byteBuffer.putFloat(((`val` and 0xFF) - 1) / 255.0f)
           }
       }
       return byteBuffer
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to having an old version of support and metadata apis.

> implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0'
> implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0'

updating from `0.1.0` to `0.4.3` solved the problem.

In general, This could happen when your runtime classpath is different than your compile time classpath.